# How can I bind some value to this.$slots.default in vue2 render function?

Tags: vuejs2, slot

As we all know, we can use this.$slots.default to create a slot.

if we use template , we can send a value to slot like this:

```
<slot name="xiaoming" value="gugugu"></slot>
```

but how can I send a value to this.$slots.default in render function in vue2?

Answer (score 0):

if just want to pass a value out to slot in render component,you can do this:

```
Vue.component('wrapper', {
  render(h) {
    return h('div', [ 
        this.$scopedSlots.default({
        test: 'works!'
        })
    ])
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

and just use it outside

```
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <wrapper>
    <template v-slot="props">
      <p>{{props.test}}</p>
    </template>
  </wrapper>
</div>
```

continue...